# Ensure to only delete an empty RabbitMQ queue, failing if the queue still has messages

Tags: rabbitmq

using below api to delete queue.

```
curl --location --request DELETE 'http://username:password@127.0.0.1:15672/api/queues/%2F/test'
```

I wish to restrict deleting if queue has messages. I can check queue length before initiating delete process of a queue but I am wondering if there is any settings which I can enable and delete api will throw error in case of non-empty queue

Comment: What about `rabbitmqctrl delete_queue` instead of the WebAPI?  https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html — I’m not sure how it’s implemented internally, so it might be a check-then-delete.

Comment: thanks but is it possible to do through api?

Answer (score 0):

One can refer for api documentation

```
http://username:password@127.0.0.1:15672/api/index.html
```

It says

```
When DELETEing a queue you can add the query string parameters if-empty=true and / or if-unused=true. These prevent the delete from succeeding if the queue contains messages, or has consumers, respectively.
```